# SharePoint 2013 psconfig after CU install

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, cumulative-update, psconfig

I'm running into an issue after installing a CU in my SharePoint 2013 farm. Installed the CU restarted my AP server, stopped services: spadminv4, sptimerv4, sptracev4 spwriterv4 and w3svc. Ran the PSCONFIG.exe command:

```
PSCONFIG.EXE -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd installcheck -noinstallcheck
```

And the upgrade fails. here's the error message in the logs:

> Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products. An exception of type
>   System.NullReferenceException was thrown.  Additional exception
>   information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseIntegrity.CheckAppOrphans()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseIntegrity.Check(SPContentDatabaseIntegrityCheckOptions
>   options)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence.ContentDatabaseDataIntegrityCheck()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence.PreUpgrade()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o,
>   Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedUpgradableObject.Upgrade(Boolean
>   recursively)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDatabase.Upgrade(Boolean
>   recursively)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunAsUser(SPUserToken userToken,
>   Boolean bResetContext, WaitCallback code, Object param)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase.Upgrade(Boolean
>   recursively)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveUpgrade(Object
>   o, Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o,
>   Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedUpgradableObject.Upgrade(Boolean
>   recursively)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveUpgrade(Object
>   o, Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o,
>   Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedUpgradableObject.Upgrade(Boolean
>   recursively)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveUpgrade(Object
>   o, Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o,
>   Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedUpgradableObject.Upgrade(Boolean
>   recursively)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveUpgrade(Object
>   o, Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o,
>   Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedUpgradableObject.Upgrade(Boolean
>   recursively)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveUpgrade(Object
>   o, Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o,
>   Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeTask.Run()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

Any ideas as to why it's failing?

Comment: what does the errorlog say in your ULS logs, Upgrade*-error.log

Comment: In my post those are the logs from the ULS logs. Sorry i didn't specify.

Comment: That's the stack trace, but what about the upgrade error log, should have a different format.

Comment: Yes, please provide extraction from (example) "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS\Upgrade-20130514-151028-117-error.log"

Comment: This issue was resolved by removing the installed following patches:
'KB4015550'
'KB4015547'
'KB4012213'
'KB3205400 - 5401'
'KB3297873'
'KB3192392'

Comment: @Vader, could you please point us to the source of this advisory? I wander what would be the impact of removing the mentioned patches. I checked some of them and as of this time, they are not superseded by newer patches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was resolved by removing the below patches:

This issue was resolved by removing the installed following patches:
"KB4015550
KB4015547
KB4012213
KB3205400 - 5401
KB3297873
KB3192392"